# Python pandas:Fast way to create a unique identifier for groups

Tags: python, pandas

I have data that looks something like this

```
df
Out[10]: 
  ID1 ID2  Price       Date
0  11  21  10.99  3/15/2016
1  11  22  11.99  3/15/2016
2  12  23      5  3/15/2016
3  11  21  10.99  3/16/2016
4  11  22  12.99  3/16/2016
5  11  21  10.99  3/17/2016
6  11  22  11.99  3/17/2016
```

The goal is to get a unique ID for each group of ID1 with particular prices for each of its ID2's, like so:

```
    # Desired Result
df
Out[14]: 
  ID1 ID2  Price       Date  UID
0  11  21  10.99  3/15/2016    1
1  11  22  11.99  3/15/2016    1
2  12  23      5  3/15/2016    7
3  11  21  10.99  3/16/2016    5
4  11  22  12.99  3/16/2016    5
5  11  21  10.99  3/17/2016    1
6  11  22  11.99  3/17/2016    1
```

Speed is an issue because of the size of the data. The best way I can come up with is below, but it is still a fair amount slower than is desirable. If anyone has a way that they think should be naturally faster I'd love to hear it. Or perhaps there is an easy way to do the within group operations in parallel to speed things up?

My method basically concatenates ID's and prices (after padding with zeros to ensure same lengths) and then takes ranks to simplify the final ID. The bottleneck is the within group concatenation done with .transform(np.sum).

```
# concatenate ID2 and Price
df['ID23'] = df['ID2'] + df['Price']

df
Out[12]: 
  ID1 ID2  Price       Date     ID23
0  11  21  10.99  3/15/2016  2110.99
1  11  22  11.99  3/15/2016  2211.99
2  12  23      5  3/15/2016      235
3  11  21  10.99  3/16/2016  2110.99
4  11  22  12.99  3/16/2016  2212.99
5  11  21  10.99  3/17/2016  2110.99
6  11  22  11.99  3/17/2016  2211.99


# groupby ID1 and Date and then concatenate the ID23's
grouped = df.groupby(['ID1','Date'])
df['summed'] = grouped['ID23'].transform(np.sum)

df
Out[16]: 
  ID1 ID2    Price       Date      ID23            summed                UID
0   6   3  0010.99  3/15/2016  30010.99  30010.9960011.99  630010.9960011.99
1   6   6  0011.99  3/15/2016  60011.99  30010.9960011.99  630010.9960011.99
2   7   7  0000005  3/15/2016  70000005          70000005          770000005
3   6   3  0010.99  3/16/2016  30010.99  30010.9960012.99  630010.9960012.99
4   6   6  0012.99  3/16/2016  60012.99  30010.9960012.99  630010.9960012.99
5   6   3  0010.99  3/17/2016  30010.99  30010.9960011.99  630010.9960011.99
6   6   6  0011.99  3/17/2016  60011.99  30010.9960011.99  630010.9960011.99

# Concatenate ID1 on the front and take rank to get simpler ID's    
df['UID'] = df['ID1'] + df['summed'] 
df['UID'] = df['UID'].rank(method = 'min')

# Drop unnecessary columns
df.drop(['ID23','summed'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

UPDATE:

To clarify, consider the original data grouped as follows:

```
grouped = df.groupby(['ID1','Date'])
    for name, group in grouped:
    print group

  ID1 ID2  Price       Date
0  11  21  10.99  3/15/2016
1  11  22  11.99  3/15/2016

  ID1 ID2  Price       Date
3  11  21  10.99  3/16/2016
4  11  22  12.99  3/16/2016

  ID1 ID2  Price       Date
5  11  21  10.99  3/17/2016
6  11  22  11.99  3/17/2016

  ID1 ID2 Price       Date
2  12  23     5  3/15/2016
```

UID's should be at the group level and match if everything about that group is identical ignoring the date. So in this case the first and third printed groups are the same, meaning that rows 0,1,5, and 6 should all get the same UID. Rows 3 and 4 belong to a different group because a price changed and therefore need a different UID. Row 2 is also a different group.

A slightly different way of looking at this problem is that I want to group as I have here, drop the date column (which was important for initially forming the groups) and then aggregate across groups which are equal once I have removed the dates.

Comment: How is it now that `'UID'` is the same for rows `0` and `1`? `'ID1'` is the same for both rows, but both `'ID2'` and `'Price'` are in fact different.

Comment: Good question. I should have explained better. ID1 is like a parent id for ID2. So rows 0 and 1 are part of the same group: the group consisting of ID1 = 11 and all its children (ID2's) on that day.I need unique ID's at that group level. The UID is the same for those rows as the final two rows despite being different days because the ID1's, ID2's, and prices are the same.

Comment: __unique__ identifier must be able to identify any row, so you either can name the columns, combination of which can guaranty uniqueness of your row or use artificial unique key like GUID. Otherwise soon or later you will have problems with your unique key algorithm. Just my 0.02$.

Comment: Thanks for your comments MaxU. I think my current method does identify any row. If I remove the rank calls which exist just to make the final result prettier the UID of 1 is actually "11210010.99220011.99". From this I can read off exactly which rows it corresponds to: ID1 = 11, ID2 = 21, Price = 10.99; then the next row in that group ID2 = 22, and so on. It is hard to name the columns conveniently because groups are of varying sizes. Sorry, I've had a hard time explaining this clearly.

Comment: What are the differences between rows 0, 3, and 5 in your data? (Why 0 and 5 has the same "UID", but not 3? Or is it a typo?)

Comment: Thanks ptrj. I've added an update that hopefully clarifies. Row 3 has a different UID because for that ID1 on that Date the other ID2 in that ID1 has a different price. The update should clarify this grouping.

Comment: future duplicate:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41594703/pandas-assign-an-index-to-each-group-identified-by-groupby

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** The code below is actually slower than OP's solution. I'm leaving it as it is for now in case someone uses it to write a better solution.

---

For visualization, I'll be using the following data:

```
df
Out[421]: 
    ID1  ID2  Price       Date
0    11   21  10.99  3/15/2016
1    11   22  11.99  3/15/2016
2    12   23   5.00  3/15/2016
3    11   21  10.99  3/16/2016
4    11   22  12.99  3/16/2016
5    11   21  10.99  3/17/2016
6    11   22  11.99  3/17/2016
7    11   22  11.99  3/18/2016
8    11   21  10.99  3/18/2016
9    12   22  11.99  3/18/2016
10   12   21  10.99  3/18/2016
11   12   23   5.00  3/19/2016
12   12   23   5.00  3/19/2016
```

First, let's group it by 'ID1' and 'Date' and aggregate the results as tuples (sorted). I also reset the index, so there is a new columns named 'index'.

```
gr = df.reset_index().groupby(['ID1','Date'], as_index = False)
df1 = gr.agg(lambda x : tuple(sorted(x)))
df1
Out[425]: 
   ID1       Date     index       ID2           Price
0   11  3/15/2016    (0, 1)  (21, 22)  (10.99, 11.99)
1   11  3/16/2016    (3, 4)  (21, 22)  (10.99, 12.99)
2   11  3/17/2016    (5, 6)  (21, 22)  (10.99, 11.99)
3   11  3/18/2016    (7, 8)  (21, 22)  (10.99, 11.99)
4   12  3/15/2016      (2,)     (23,)          (5.0,)
5   12  3/18/2016   (9, 10)  (21, 22)  (10.99, 11.99)
6   12  3/19/2016  (11, 12)  (23, 23)      (5.0, 5.0)
```

After all grouping is done, I'll use indices from column `'index'` to access rows from `df` (they'd better be unique). (Notice also that `df1.index` and `df1['index']` are completely different things.)

Now, let's group `'index'` (skipping dates):

```
df2 = df1.groupby(['ID1','ID2','Price'], as_index = False)['index'].sum()
df2
Out[427]: 
   ID1       ID2           Price               index
0   11  (21, 22)  (10.99, 11.99)  (0, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8)
1   11  (21, 22)  (10.99, 12.99)              (3, 4)
2   12  (21, 22)  (10.99, 11.99)             (9, 10)
3   12     (23,)          (5.0,)                (2,)
4   12  (23, 23)      (5.0, 5.0)            (11, 12)
```

I believe this is the grouping needed for the problem, so we can now add labels to `df`. For example like this:

```
df['GID'] = -1
for i, t in enumerate(df2['index']):
    df.loc[t,'GID'] = i

df
Out[430]: 
    ID1  ID2  Price       Date  GID
0    11   21  10.99  3/15/2016    0
1    11   22  11.99  3/15/2016    0
2    12   23   5.00  3/15/2016    3
3    11   21  10.99  3/16/2016    1
4    11   22  12.99  3/16/2016    1
5    11   21  10.99  3/17/2016    0
6    11   22  11.99  3/17/2016    0
7    11   22  11.99  3/18/2016    0
8    11   21  10.99  3/18/2016    0
9    12   22  11.99  3/18/2016    2
10   12   21  10.99  3/18/2016    2
11   12   23   5.00  3/19/2016    4
12   12   23   5.00  3/19/2016    4
```

Or in a possibly faster but tricky way:

```
# EXPERIMENTAL CODE!
df3 = df2['index'].apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index()
df3.index = df3[0].astype(int)
df['GID'] = df3['level_0']
```

Comment: I like your solution ptrj. Using tuples is a lot slicker than concatenating a bunch of strings like I was doing. I was sadly surprised that your method ends up being a bit slower though. I'm guessing this is because summing over a groupby is [cythonized](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#cython-optimized-aggregation-functions) (?) so that even with slicker code, the gr.agg() step is slower.

Comment: @Archimedes I didn't test the performance. Is the groupby with `tuple(sorted(x))` so slow or the whole code?

Comment: Yes, it is the gr.agg(lambda x : tuple(sorted(x))) line that takes by far the majority of the time.

Comment: @Archimedes The culprit may be `sorted`. If it is so (i.e. if `gr.agg(lambda x : tuple(x))` runs much faster), then you could try some workaround, for example sorting df beforehand by 'ID2' and 'Price' (groupby should preserve the order). You may also try passing `sort = False` to each groupby.

Comment: It looks like removing the sorts makes little difference, unfortunately. It might be worth noting that in my data in most cases there is only one ID2 for a given ID1. So in most cases the sort isn't doing anything.

Comment: @Archimedes You're right. I think I missed the point of the problem. Should I delete the answer or let it stay for now?

Comment: I'm new to posting here, but I think it is still useful information.