# Pandas: assign an index to each group identified by groupby

Tags: python, pandas

When using groupby(), how can I create a DataFrame with a new column containing an index of the group number, similar to `dplyr::group_indices` in R.  For example, if I have

```
>>> df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,1,2,2,2],'b':[1,1,2,1,1,2]})
>>> df
   a  b
0  1  1
1  1  1
2  1  2
3  2  1
4  2  1
5  2  2
```

How can I get a DataFrame like

```
   a  b  idx
0  1  1  1
1  1  1  1
2  1  2  2
3  2  1  3
4  2  1  3
5  2  2  4
```

(the order of the `idx` indexes doesn't matter)

Comment: As of 0.20.2 you can use [ngroup](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html).

Comment: Yeah, `ngroup` seems to be the simplest and fasted choice for 0.20.2 forward (note that @calumyou has added it below as an answer), although other answers may still be interesting as they give you different values for the group ID.

Comment: `ngroup` used in this answer also:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46067934/how-to-label-rows-by-unique-pairs-of-other-rows-in-pandas-0-19-2

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's a concise way using `drop_duplicates` and `merge` to get a unique identifier.

```
group_vars = ['a','b']
df.merge( df.drop_duplicates( group_vars ).reset_index(), on=group_vars )

   a  b  index
0  1  1      0
1  1  1      0
2  1  2      2
3  2  1      3
4  2  1      3
5  2  2      5
```

The identifier in this case goes 0,2,3,5 (just a residual of original index) but this could be easily changed to 0,1,2,3 with an additional `reset_index(drop=True)`.

**Update:**  Newer versions of pandas (0.20.2) offer a simpler way to do this with the `ngroup` method as noted in a comment to the question above by @Constantino and a subsequent answer by @CalumYou.  I'll leave this here as an alternate approach but `ngroup` seems like the better way to do this in most cases.

Comment: Ingenious and blazingly fast.  If an ordered index is desired then just need to use pandas.factorize on the index column and replace it. This should be the accepted answer!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the group (a=1, b=1) now has multiple new indexes.
The OP asked for a unique index for each group.

Answer (score 56):

Here is the solution using `ngroup` (available as of pandas 0.20.2) from [a comment above by Constantino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41594703/pandas-assign-an-index-to-each-group-identified-by-groupby/51329888#comment85160562_41594703).

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,1,2,2,2],'b':[1,1,2,1,1,2]})
df['idx'] = df.groupby(['a', 'b']).ngroup()
df
```

```
   a  b  idx
0  1  1    0
1  1  1    0
2  1  2    1
3  2  1    2
4  2  1    2
5  2  2    3
```

Comment: it would be good to benchmark this on a larger dataframe with more groups but I think this still will be fastest (not to mention simplest).  I benchmarked on 576 groups (26x26) and 100,000 rows and ngroup was as fast or faster than the others.

Answer (score 16):

A simple way to do that would be to concatenate your grouping columns (so that each combination of their values represents a uniquely distinct element), then convert it to a [pandas Categorical](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html) and keep only its labels:

```
df['idx'] = pd.Categorical(df['a'].astype(str) + '_' + df['b'].astype(str)).codes
df

    a   b   idx
0   1   1   0
1   1   1   0
2   1   2   1
3   2   1   2
4   2   1   2
5   2   2   3
```

Edit: changed `labels` properties to `codes` as the former seem to be deprecated

Edit2: Added a separator as suggested by Authman Apatira

Comment: You can additionally add `1` to achieve the desired OP but otherwise +1

Comment: Neat solution, thanks. Is there a neat way to concatenate the column names if I have a load of them, without repeated .astype(str) calls?

Comment: Use `.codes` to avoid `FutureWarning` message of `.labels`

Comment: Yes, any operation on the columns that generate unique elements would work. The `astype(str)` is just convenient here. You could, for instance replace it by the application of a lambda that concatenates the values: `pd.Categorical(df[['a', 'b']].apply(lambda r: ''.join([str(i) for i in r]), axis=1)).codes`

Comment: @foglerit thanks. A neat equivalent is something like `df[['a','b']].astype(str).apply("".join, 1)`

Comment: You guys wanna be careful merging columns this way. a=11, b=1 would produce the same group code as a=1, b=11, when in reality they are different. Be sure to add some kind of separator between columns if you wanna do it this way. I'd like to see this method benchmarked against a proper groupby though... both for memory and processor requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Definetely not the most straightforward solution, but here is what I would do (comments in the code):

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,1,2,2,2],'b':[1,1,2,1,1,2]})

#create a dummy grouper id by just joining desired rows
df["idx"] = df[["a","b"]].astype(str).apply(lambda x: "".join(x),axis=1)

print df
```

That would generate an unique idx for each combination of `a` and `b`.

```
   a  b idx
0  1  1  11
1  1  1  11
2  1  2  12
3  2  1  21
4  2  1  21
5  2  2  22
```

But this is still a rather silly index (think about some more complex values in columns `a` and `b`. So let's clear the index:

```
# create a dictionary of dummy group_ids and their index-wise representation
dict_idx = dict(enumerate(set(df["idx"])))

# switch keys and values, so you can use dict in .replace method
dict_idx = {y:x for x,y in dict_idx.iteritems()}

#replace values with the generated dict
df["idx"].replace(dict_idx,inplace=True)

print df
```

That would produce the desired output:

```
   a  b  idx
0  1  1    0
1  1  1    0
2  1  2    1
3  2  1    2
4  2  1    2
5  2  2    3
```

Answer (score 2):

A way that I believe is faster than the current accepted answer by about an order of magnitude (timing results below):

```
def create_index_usingduplicated(df, grouping_cols=['a', 'b']):
    df.sort_values(grouping_cols, inplace=True)
    # You could do the following three lines in one, I just thought 
    # this would be clearer as an explanation of what's going on:
    duplicated = df.duplicated(subset=grouping_cols, keep='first')
    new_group = ~duplicated
    return new_group.cumsum()
```

Timing results:

```
a = np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=int(1e5))
b = np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=int(1e5))
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': a, 'b': b})

In [6]: %timeit df['idx'] = pd.Categorical(df['a'].astype(str) + df['b'].astype(str)).codes
1 loop, best of 3: 375 ms per loop

In [7]: %timeit df['idx'] = create_index_usingduplicated(df, grouping_cols=['a', 'b'])
100 loops, best of 3: 17.7 ms per loop
```

Comment: With my data, I get `group = pd.Categorical(data['day'])` to be about 5x faster than `new_group = ~data.sort_values('day').duplicated(subset='day', keep='first'); group = new_group.cumsum()`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is such a trivial problem. Here is a somewhat convoluted solution that first sorts the grouping columns and then checks whether each row is different than the previous row and if so accumulates by 1. Check further below for an answer with string data.

```
df.sort_values(['a', 'b']).diff().fillna(0).ne(0).any(1).cumsum().add(1)
```

Output

```
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    3
5    4
dtype: int64
```

So breaking this up into steps, lets see the output of `df.sort_values(['a', 'b']).diff().fillna(0)` which checks if each row is different than the previous row. Any non-zero entry indicates a new group.

```
     a    b
0  0.0  0.0
1  0.0  0.0
2  0.0  1.0
3  1.0 -1.0
4  0.0  0.0
5  0.0  1.0
```

A new group only need to have a single column different so this is what `.ne(0).any(1)` checks - not equal to 0 for any of the columns. And then just a cumulative sum to keep track of the groups.

#### Answer for columns as strings

```
#create fake data and sort it
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':list('aabbaccdc'),'b':list('aabaacddd')})
df1 = df.sort_values(['a', 'b'])
```

output of `df1`

```
   a  b
0  a  a
1  a  a
4  a  a
3  b  a
2  b  b
5  c  c
6  c  d
8  c  d
7  d  d
```

Take similar approach by checking if group has changed

```
df1.ne(df1.shift().bfill()).any(1).cumsum().add(1)

0    1
1    1
4    1
3    2
2    3
5    4
6    5
8    5
7    6
```