# To create a new column to assign a new ID using loop or numpy, where

Tags: python, numpy, loops

I'm a little new to Python. I am working on movement data. I have ID, location, speed, time, and destination columns. My `dataframe` looks like this:

| shipid | destination | lon | lat | speed | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 508040000 | Brunei | 139.356 | 34.172 | 13 | 2016/01/12 16:44:03 |
| 508040000 | Brunei | 139.356 | 34.173 | 12.9 | 2016/01/12 16:44:03 |
| 508040000 | Brunei | 139.781 | 35.245 | 12.7 | 2016/01/12 16:44:03 |
| 508040000 | Busan | 139.358 | 34.172 | 15.8 | 2016/03/01 16:09:36 |
| 508040000 | Busan | 139.359 | 34.173 | 15.6 | 2016/03/01 16:10:06 |
| 508040000 | Busan | 139.362 | 34.177 | 15.9 | 2016/03/01 16:11:07 |
| 431000792 | Tokyo | 139.673 | 34.842 | 11 | 2016/04/01 22:17:51 |
| 431000792 | Tokyo | 139.683 | 34.914 | 11 | 2016/04/01 22:41:11 |
| 431000792 | Tokyo | 139.684 | 34.926 | 10.3 | 2016/04/01 22:45:20 |
| 431000792 | Aomi | 140.760717 | 40.8771 | 0.1 | 2016/05/03 22:03:02 |
| 431000792 | Aomi | 140.759967 | 40.877033 | 0 | 2016/05/03 23:54:19 |
| 431000792 | Aomi | 140.760117 | 40.876917 | 0 | 2016/05/04 0:06:00 |

I want to loop or iterate through ID and destination to create a new trip ID column.

| shipid | destination | lat | lon | speed | time | tripid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 508040000 | Brunei | 139.356 | 34.172 | 13 | 2016/01/12 16:44:03 | 1 |
| 508040000 | Brunei | 139.356 | 34.173 | 12.9 | 2016/01/12 16:44:03 | 1 |
| 508040000 | Brunei | 139.781 | 35.245 | 12.7 | 2016/01/12 16:44:03 | 1 |
| 508040000 | Busan | 139.358 | 34.172 | 15.8 | 2016/03/01 16:09:36 | 2 |
| 508040000 | Busan | 139.359 | 34.173 | 15.6 | 2016/03/01 16:10:06 | 2 |
| 508040000 | Busan | 139.362 | 34.177 | 15.9 | 2016/03/01 16:11:07 | 2 |
| 431000792 | Tokyo | 139.673 | 34.842 | 11 | 2016/04/01 22:17:51 | 1 |
| 431000792 | Tokyo | 139.683 | 34.914 | 11 | 2016/04/01 22:41:11 | 1 |
| 431000792 | Tokyo | 139.684 | 34.926 | 10.3 | 2016/04/01 22:45:20 | 1 |
| 431000792 | Aomi | 140.760717 | 40.8771 | 0.1 | 2016/05/03 22:03:02 | 2 |
| 431000792 | Aomi | 140.759967 | 40.877033 | 0 | 2016/05/03 23:54:19 | 2 |
| 431000792 | Aomi | 140.760117 | 40.876917 | 0 | 2016/05/04 0:06:00 | 2 |

So I wrote as follows

```
for shipid in df.shipid.unique():
    tripid=1
    for destination in df.destination.unique():
        df['tripid'] = np.where(df['destination']==df['destination'].shift(-1),tripid, tripid+1)
```

The code creates a new column `tripid` where every row is assigned "1", except for the last row of each destination, where "2" is assigned.

I want to assign a unique ID to each ship with the same destination as 1, 2, 3.

I am not sure of what to use, either loop or iteration, etc. I tried to use it for a loop and the error shows the series is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this solve your problem?

```py
import pandas as pd

# Example dataframe:
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'shipid': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
    'destination': ['Brunei', 'Brunei', 'Brunei', 'Busan', 'Busan', 'Tokyo', 'Tokyo']}
)

df['tripid'] = df.groupby(['destination']).cumcount() + 1
```

| shipid | destination | tripid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Brunei | 1 |
| 1 | Brunei | 2 |
| 1 | Brunei | 3 |
| 1 | Busan | 1 |
| 1 | Busan | 2 |
| 2 | Tokyo | 1 |
| 2 | Tokyo | 2 |

You can also group by both `shipid` **and** `destination`:

```py
df['tripid'] = df.groupby(['shipid', 'destination']).cumcount() + 1
```

---

Or maybe you need this?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51329888/14627505

```py
df['tripid'] = df.groupby(['shipid', 'destination']).ngroup() + 1
```

| shipid | destination | tripid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Brunei | 1 |
| 1 | Brunei | 1 |
| 1 | Brunei | 1 |
| 1 | Busan | 2 |
| 1 | Busan | 2 |
| 2 | Tokyo | 3 |
| 2 | Tokyo | 3 |

Comment: **groupby** and **ngroup()** works for the problem. Also **.cumcount()** will be a useful tool for each movement tracking. Thank you.